# git clone failing with unreachable

Tags: git

I know that there are many other questions on this but none seem to either be on point or I've tried them.

I am trying to install Kismet but get to the step `git clone https://github.com/kismetwireless/kismet.git`

I then get the dreaded
cloning into ...
fatal: unable to access ... Failed to connect to github.com port 443: network is unreachable.

I have done this tons of times from my home so I don't suspect firewall.  I have tried the proxy with `git config --global http.proxy http://domain.local ..`  I tried to use what i found online but it contained \v (VT) which i couldn't figure out how to do.

I have a github username and password and am not sure if that goes any good.  If anyone could give me detailed instructions would appreciate it since this type of thing is not in my wheelhouse.

Comment: Well, it seems to be a network issue which is unrelated to git. Can you ping github.com or open https://github.com in your browser? "Network unreachable" usually means that you have no route to the remote host.

Answer (score -1):

I think the below command will help you.

```
git clone -b master https://github.com/kismetwireless/kismet.git kismetwireless
```

It will clone the master branch into a local folder named `kismetwireless`. As you already mentioned you have github account, then you can also optionally use:

```
git clone -b master https://USER-NAME:PASSWORD@github.com/kismetwireless/kismet.git kismetwireless
```

Comment: Why would this fix a "network is unreachable" error?

Comment: since he did not specify the branch, i think it may work.